# Can I use chromeless player/playback stats with the new Youtube Player iframe embed style?

Tags: api, video, youtube, youtube-api

The [Youtube Player API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html?playerType=chromeless&playerVersion=as3) has a bunch of functionality that I'm interested in, such as the chromeless player, playback statistics (where you can see the current state of the player, current time etc) and the ability to set volume levels.

But I've been using the [new iframe embed style](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html). Is there a way to use those features with the new style? If not, does anyone know if/when there will be a way? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new iframe embed style uses the html5 video tags, so the old api wont work. Perhaps considering javascript to modify the player, but at that point I don't know for another way doing it. It's very new...